# Ubuntu forward X over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I've currently have the following situation.

I have a server, that is connected to the internet with ssh (on a non 22 port). This is an ubuntu server without X server. Now i have a machine inside this network, that is used as a desktop machine.

Is it possible to forward all request on a specific port (for the server) directly to that desktop machine, to be able to use the Xserver over SSH?

Comment: What OS, terminal software and X server are you using on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the -X argument when connecting to your server using ssh, and you'll be able to launch applications on the server that are displayed on the client.

Comment: Eraser, i need indeed connect to the server, but this server doesn't have xserver installed. And i need to run applications from the desktop that's behind the server.

Comment: Ok, so you want to connect to the server, and the server will actually forward your request to the desktop?

Comment: The just create an ssh tunnel. See the -L arg documentation in the ssh man page.

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to do this is to install VNC Server on the Desktop machine.

Then you can do the following from your laptop with RealVNC Viewer installed:
`vncviewer desktop:1 -via user@servername.domain.com`

To connect directly to the desktop. This will automatically SSH to servername.domain.com, forward a port to the destination VNC server, then connect to that port.
Replace **desktop** with the *internal* DNS name or IP of the desktop, and of course the rest should be obvious there.

As an alternative there's also X forwarding, which you can bounce through a tunnel, but XLib does not make any attempts to optimize for bandwidth.